# Python - writing cleaner (better) code - constant declaring and redeclaring of variables

Tags: python, variables, coding-style

For my first foray into python, I wrote some parsing code that works as I intended.

I would like to share this code with some other external folk (because the functio it performs might be useful to them), and to be honest, I'm quite ashamed of my clunky and over the top coding... the actual work part of the code is very short, but I seem to have spent about 70% of the file declaring and redeclaring variables....

I'm pretty sure its not the right way of doing this, and I'm not asking for someone to line by line pick apart my coding, but some basic pointers around tidying up the mess would awesome.

And yes, todo is to comment the various section before I push it out....

```
    import re, os
def setGlobals():
###################### match returns
global sigVersionMatch
global filepathMatch 
global statusMatch
global puidMatch
global mimeMatch 
global status2Match
global warningMatch 
global filenameMatch
global fileExtensionMatch
###################### Flags and counters
global lineCounter
global headerFlag
global newLine
###################### header variables
global headerLineOne
global headerLineTwo
global sigVersion 
###################### searches as a variable
global SearchForStatus 
global SearchForFilename 
global SearchForFilepath 
global SearchForPuid
global SearchForMime
global SearchForStatus2
global SearchForWarning
global SearchForFileExtension
####################### searchstring variables
global filepath
global status
global puid
global mime
global status2
global warning
global filename
global sigVersion
global fileExtension
###################### file name lists
global newfile
####################### Flag and counters settings
headerFlag = 0
lineCounter = 0
newLine=""
###################### search strings headers
headerLineOne = re.compile(r'(DROID Version,)')
headerLineTwo = re.compile(r'(Status,File,Warning,)')
sigVersion = re.compile(r'(?<=SigFile Version,")[0-9]*')
###################### search strings body
filepath = re.compile(r'(?P<filepath>(F:\\ExLib.*\w))')
status = re.compile(r'(?P<status>(?<!,")(Positive|Not identified|Tentative))')  
puid = re.compile(r'(?P<puid>(x-fmt/|fmt/)([0-9]{1,3}))')   
mime = re.compile(r'(?P<mime>([a-zA-Z]*\/([a-zA-Z]|\-)*(?=",)))')   
status2 = re.compile(r'(?P<status2>(Positive \(Specific Format\)|Positive \(Generic Format\)|(Tentative)(?=(",""))))')
warning = re.compile(r'(?P<warning>(Possible file extension mismatch))') 
filename = re.compile(r'(?P<filenam>(V[0-9]\-.*\w))')
headerLineOne = re.compile(r'(DROID Version,)')
headerLineTwo = re.compile(r'(Status,File,Warning,)')
sigVersion = re.compile(r'(?<=SigFile Version,")[0-9]*')
fileExtension = re.compile(r'(?<=\.).*')
def doSearches(line):
global SearchForStatus 
global SearchForFilename 
global SearchForFilepath 
global SearchForPuid
global SearchForMime
global SearchForStatus2
global SearchForWarning
global SearchForFileExtension
global status
global filename
global filepath
global puid
global mime
global status2
global warning
global fileExtension
global filepathMatch 
global statusMatch
global puidMatch
global mimeMatch 
global status2Match
global warningMatch 
global filenameMatch
global fileExtensionMatch
####### do searches
SearchForStatus = status.search(line)
SearchForFilename = filename.search(line) 
SearchForFilepath = filepath.search(line) 
SearchForPuid = puid.search(line)
SearchForMime = mime.search(line)
SearchForStatus2 = status2.search(line)
SearchForWarning = warning.search(line)
###### convert search returns to strings
if SearchForStatus:
    doInitialseVariables()
    statusMatch = str(SearchForStatus.group())
if SearchForFilename:
    filenameMatch = str(SearchForFilename.group())
    SearchForFileExtension = fileExtension.search(filenameMatch)
    if SearchForFileExtension:
        fileExtensionMatch = str(SearchForFileExtension.group())        
if SearchForFilepath:
    filepathMatch = str(SearchForFilepath.group())      
if SearchForPuid:
    puidMatch = str(SearchForPuid.group())
if SearchForMime:
    mimeMatch = str(SearchForMime.group())
if SearchForStatus2:
    status2Match = str(SearchForStatus2.group())
if SearchForWarning:
    warningMatch = str(SearchForWarning.group())
if statusMatch == str("Not identified"):
    doBuildLine(line)
if SearchForPuid:
    doBuildLine(line)   
def doBuildLine(line):
global filepathMatch 
global statusMatch
global puidMatch
global mimeMatch 
global status2Match
global warningMatch 
global filenameMatch
global fileExtensionMatch
global newLine
global lineCounter
global newfile
lineCounter = lineCounter + 1
print lineCounter
newLine = "3,"+ str(sigVersionMatch)+",slow," + str(lineCounter) + ",,," + str(filepathMatch) + "," + str(filenameMatch) + ",," + str(statusMatch) + ",,," + str(fileExtensionMatch) + ",," + str(warningMatch) + ",,," + str(puidMatch) + "," + str(mimeMatch) + ",,\n"
outfile = open(newfile,"a")
outfile.write(newLine)
outfile.close() 
def doInitialseVariables():
global filepathMatch 
global statusMatch
global puidMatch
global mimeMatch 
global status2Match
global warningMatch 
global filenamMatch
global lineOnceFlag
global fileExtensionMatch
global lineOneFlag
global lineTwoFlag
puidMatch = ""
mimeMatch= ""
status2Match = ""
warningMatch = "" 
statusMatch = ""
filepathMatch = ""
filenameMatch = ""  
fileExtensionMatch = ""
def doGetHeaderVariables(line):#matches header lines, strips sig version, saves as sigVersionMatch
global sigVersionMatch
M1 = headerLineOne.search(line)
M2 = headerLineTwo.search(line)
M3 = sigVersion.search(line)
if M3:
    sigVersionMatch = str(M3.group())
def doStartProcessing(line):
global headerFlag
global lineCounter
if headerFlag == 0: #stops header match testing once successfully complete
    doGetHeaderVariables(line)
    headerFlag = 1
doSearches(line)
if __name__ == "__main__":
setGlobals()
global newfile
doInitialseVariables() #sets up the variable space to begin 
directory = "C:\droid\logs\\"
extension = ".csv"
list_of_files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]
for currentfile in list_of_files:
    logpath = str(directory)+str(currentfile)
    newfile = str(directory) + "cleaned\\" + str(currentfile)
    for line in open(logpath,'r'):
        doStartProcessing(line)
    headerFlag = 0
    lineCounter = 0
```

Comment: Usually a *single* occurrence of the keyword `global` makes me rethink my design...

Comment: You definitely should NOT use that much global variables. Actually you should not use global variables at all except in exceptional cases.

Comment: I figured as much - but couldn't find away of doing it 'properly'.

Comment: what the heck are all those globals for?

Comment: infinte monkeys & typewriters.... I am no coder, I simply poked at things until it did what I wanted it to do. I fully acknowledge its not the right way, or even 'a' way, and am looking for pointers to help me learn.

Comment: yes, stop with globals!  Although it reminds me of perl code I used to write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You only need to use the `global` statement for names that you are going to reassign in the function.  You can access any name you want without it, including accessing it to call a method on it that will modify the object.
2. Your code would be vastly simplified if you used a class.  The global variables would become attributes of the object, and your functions would become methods.
3. Don't use tabs to indent, use spaces (the code would be readable above if you do this).
4. You don't need to compile regexes before you use them.  The `re` module compiles and caches for you automatically.

Comment: Hmm - this sounds important, and valuable. I am picking this up as I go along, so my hacky code is there because I found away of doing what I wanted to do. Could you point me towards a primer on classes? I have never had a coding lesson in my life, so my basics are flakey at best... :(

Answer (score 1):

1. If you haven't already go through the tutorial:

   - http://docs.python.org/tutorial/
   - If questions come up about something you come across, raise a question here.
2. Read [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

   - This is the bible of python code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously suggest [Mark Katz's "Learning Python"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158068) for really good sections on the uses of global and local variables, function declarations, etc.

Not to be mean at all, cause I know I've kludged together stuff like this early on, but put this code in a password-protected file somewhere, read that book, rewrite it, and then show it to the public.  Never let anyone but yourself have the password to that file.  Its main use will be in reminding you how far you've come in an amazingly short time.

That said, really good go on getting that much regex working for you.

Comment: Thank you. Take down coming up! :)

Answer (score 1):

[*How to Think Like a Computer Scientist*](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy/) Is a great book for beginners, and it uses Python as its language. It covers classes and objects in a clear way with good examples. Bonus: it's free, but don't let that fool you. :)